# Where clause with having count breaks query

Tags: mysql

This query isn't returning what I though it should:

```
Select user_id 
from subs 
where status = 'Failed' 
and next_run_dt = '2016-08-04'  
and active = '1'
group by user_id having count(status) = 2
```

Table structure and sample data:

```
id__|__status__|__next_run_dt__|__user_id__|__active__|
    |          |               |           |          |
 1  | Failed   | 2016-08-04    |    3      |    1     |
 ___|__________|_______________|___________|__________|
    |          |               |           |          |
 2  | Failed   | 2016-08-04    |    4      |    1     |
 ___|__________|_______________|___________|__________|
    |          |               |           |          |
 3  | Failed   | 2016-08-04    |    3      |    1     |
 ___|__________|_______________|___________|__________|
```

> The query should return the user_id of `3` because that user has two entries with at status of `Failed`.  The query returns the user_id if I remove `and next_run_dt = '2016-08-04'` (date column).

What am I missing?

EDIT:  There also exists the possibility that a `user_id` can also have a `next_run_dt` of null as well

Comment: It looks perfectly fine to me; I can only imagine that there is a date format issue. What does it return when you remove the group-by and the having clauses? If it gives you _no_ rows, it is clear that the where-condition on the date is off; if it gives you _all_ lines, I am lost too.

Comment: What is the datatype on next_run_dt?

Comment: @Aganju, removing the group by and having returns all entries where `Failed` and `active`.

Comment: @atjoedonahue date column

Comment: I learned SQL like 20 years ago, and I would think it should be `HAVING COUNT(*) = 2`, but it should not make any difference. I am at a loss, sorry.

Comment: With your sample data the given query returns the correct result. Check the [`Fiddler`](http://rextester.com/OXSRI36957)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's a date column? If it's datetime, you'll have problems.
Your query works for me on SQLFiddle.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0bab6/1